# A word for 'monotonous' or 'repetitive' with a positive connotation

Tags: single-word-requests

For some time I have been looking for a word that describes a repetitive or monotonous task in a positive light. In particular, some people find simple tasks like grocery shopping, counting pennies, or making highly detailed drawings to be soothing. The closest thing I've found to such a word is the phrase 'comfortingly repetitive.' Synonyms for 'monotonous,' 'comforting,' 'soothing,' and 'repetitive' have turned up nothing close.

A vaguely related word might be 'stereotypy,' though this word is a noun that (negatively) describes a pathological behavior, whereas I am looking for a positive adjective. Maybe someone with a stereotypy would describe the tasks they do using the sought-after word.

A noun for a 'comfortingly repetitive task' would also be helpful, so long as it had a positive connotation.

Comment: If you can use something slightly colloquial: *in a groove*. [1. Immersed in a particular task and thus working smoothly and efficiently.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+a+groove)

Comment: Possibly *routine*, but that’s neutral rather than strictly positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A repetitive task can be said to be [meditative](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meditative)

> marked by or conducive to meditation

Meditation is defined as

> to engage in contemplation or reflection

Any repetitive task that doesn’t require active thought can be meditative. Also, some people use the term [zen](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Zen)

> a state of calm attentiveness in which one's actions are guided by intuition rather than by conscious effort

Answer (score 0):

[Rhythmic](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rhythmic)

> of, relating to, or characterized by rhythm, as in movement or sound; metrical, periodic, or regularly recurring

One can also write of the "rhythms of life."  (The association with music does help with the connotation, I suspect.)

Answer (score -1):

There is "second nature" but that doesn't carry quite the same connotation. It implies there is no stress involved, not necessarily comfort.